# How can I remove a part of a string in C# when the string contains non-ascii characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-web-api

I asked a question about how to remove pronunciation and the non-ascii value that follows it from part of a string response.Body that contains this:

```
  {...."pronunciation" : "ʌ'bændʌnmʌnt", "frequency" : 2.98}
```

The word following pronunciation is containing characters that seem to be not working with Regex.

The suggestion was to use:

```
  Regex.Replace(response.Body, @"\s*""pronunciation""\s*:[^,]*,", "")
```

But this does not seem to work.

Is there another way that I could reduce the section of my string that starts with "pronunciation" completely.

For reference here are details on the characters used:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet

Note the reason I would like to remove it is because I am not using it and also when I try the following code it gives an exception with a message pointing to the value of the pronunciation as being the cause of the error:

```
 RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Body);
```

Just a thought. If Regex is not working then would it be reasonable to have a solution that looked for the position of pronunciation and of frequency and removed the value by doing a substring? I would also be okay to accept that as a suggestion if nobody has an idea how to solve it with Regex.

Update:

Here is the data I added from the original question. Note that the Json string has been formatted. Normally it's not formatted and is just a plain string with no new lines:

I have this API call:

```
 HttpResponse<string> response = Unirest
                .get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word.Name)
                .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxxx")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .asJson<string>();
```

For words it retrieve this type of response:

```
{
    "word" : "abandonment",
    "results" : [{
            "definition" : "withdrawing support or help despite allegiance or responsibility",
            "partOfSpeech" : "noun",
            "typeOf" : ["disposal", "disposition"],
            "hasTypes" : ["throwing away", "discard"],
            "derivation" : ["abandon"]
        }
    ],
    "syllables" : {
        "count" : 4,
        "list" : ["a", "ban", "don", "ment"]
    },
    "pronunciation" : "ʌ'bændʌnmʌnt",
    "frequency" : 2.98
}
```

Here's the API that I was using to get the data:

```
  https://market.mashape.com/wordsapi/wordsapi#
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Some transcriptions can be *pure* English (no non-ASCII symbols), e.g. `"bet"`; probably you want to remove two values in quotes (or value in JSON)

Comment: @S.Akbari - I don't need the pronunciation value so my desired output would be the string with that removed completely.  The reason I need it out is that I try to deserialize and it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the text data using the correct encoding? There's nothing wrong with the non-ASCII characters in your JSON. And in general, parsing JSON with a Regex is just asking for trouble :)

Comment: I think it may then be that the string contains a single quote. I read on the web site here that this could cause problems:  https://www.wordsapi.com/docs#pronunciation

Comment: Note that [your regex works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%22pronunciation%22%5cs*%3a%5b%5e%2c%5d*%2c&i=%7b%0d%0a++++%7d%2c%0d%0a++++%22pronunciation%22+%3a+%22%ca%8c%27b%c3%a6nd%ca%8cnm%ca%8cnt%22%2c%0d%0a++++%22frequency%22+%3a+2.98%0d%0a%7d) , so the problem is not with the regex, but the string itself. Or you forgot to assign the replacement result to the variable. :)